# How to send String Array to 4 clients at a time from server

Tags: android

Suppose 4 clients are connected to a Server.

- Server has String Array with size 4 and each index of Array contains  different String.

What i want to say is:

- index[1] String should be sent to first client.
- index[2] String should be sent to 2nd client.
- index[3] String should be sent to 3rd client.
- index[4] String should be sent to 4th client.

How to send this strings from array at a same time to 4 different users from Server to clients?

Comment: simply you  can use for loop for this and index[i] send to 'ith' client.

Comment: what server? this is so high level and, at the same time, low level, that a (one) answer is almost impossible.

Comment: And "same time" in a strict sense is only possible using timed operations – and even then you'll have msecs or nsecs of difference. Please be much more specific about your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what server? this is so high level and, at the same time, low level, that a (one) answer is almost impossible. –  Bondax

As Bondax says it would be hard to give a useful answer for implementation, but assuming a high level sudocode answer is desired

```
for(int iClient = 0; iClient < Server.numClients; iClient++)
{
    Client client = Server.GetClient(iClient)
    String string = Server.GetString(iClient)
    Client.SendMessage(string);
}
```

Of course assuming you are writing the server software yourself and the server holds the details of both clients and the strings you could just have a method called `SendToAll` or similar Which simply iterates through the clients sending the string.

```
Server::SendToAll()
{
    for(int iClient = 0; iClient < Server.numClients; iClient++)
        clients[iClient].SendMessage(strings[iClient]);
};
```

N.B. This is sudocode, I will revise to be more specific if more information is added to the question

Comment: Clients[] is those which contains all clients,that is connected to server??

Comment: How to recieve clients this strings at a time

Comment: How I handle from client side.When this string array received at a time to each player?  Because Each Client have Play Button after connection to the server.So I press at a time one button of one client.How to handle other clients string  Because I not pressed same time All "play " Buttons

Answer (score 0):

using Android GCM http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html, to develop a push notification mechanism